# DBus - How can I list all services (bus name) in the system bus?

Tags: ipc, introspection, dbus

I'd like to create a program that connects to dbus --system bus and list all services (bus_names) connected. Just like "qdbus".

Does anybody could help me?

My dbus version is dbus-1.2.24 and I'm programming in C (without bindings).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [Qt DBus List Names example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/dbus-listnames-listnames-cpp.html).

```
QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
QDBusInterface dbus_iface("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/org/freedesktop/DBus",
                          "org.freedesktop.DBus", bus);
qDebug() << dbus_iface.call("ListNames").arguments().at(0);
```

Here's an example using the command line:

```
# qdbus --literal --system org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
{"org.freedesktop.DBus", ":1.23", ":1.31", "org.freedesktop.Avahi", ":1.24", ":1.26"}
# dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --print-reply=literal /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
   array [
      org.freedesktop.DBus      :1.23      org.freedesktop.Avahi      :1.24      :1.33      :1.26   ]
```

You may also just want to go directly to the source, tools/qdbus/qdbus/qdbus.cpp, in the qt source. There you'll notice that if `args.empty()` it calls `printServiceNames()` which just returns the result of `registeredServiceNames()` called on an interface for the system bus. Then, that code does the following:

```
QDBusReply<QStringList> QDBusConnectionInterface::registeredServiceNames() const
{
    return internalConstCall(QDBus::AutoDetect, QLatin1String("ListNames"));
}
```

Now we've come full circle.

Comment: The link in this answer has been broken/moved to
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/dbus-listnames-listnames-cpp.html

Comment: Here is link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/a-list-of-available-dbus-services# to display using send-dbus:

Comment: Actually the best Qt site for dbus-listnames is: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-listnames-example.html